# Get the generateResources task's associated directory dynamically at build time

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

With android-gradle, I can get the processResources task's associated directory using the Output API with :

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  variant.outputs.each { output ->
    def resDir = output.processResources.resDir;
    // for flavorARelease variant, this resDir is : 
    // build/intermediates/res/flavorA/release/
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to retrieve, *without hardcoding it*, the folder `/build/generated/res/something/rs/flavorA/release/`

This folder might be retrievable with the generateResources task but I didnt find a way to get this specific task (`tasks["generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Resources"]` may not be a good idea ?

Thank you for your help.